# Gradle to Maven

Tags: maven, gradle, avro

I am trying to convert gradle to maven.

**Project Structure**

```
test
|____ test1
        |____ pom.xml
|____ test2
        |____ pom.xml
|____ pom.xml
```

**build.gradle** in **test2**

```
plugins {
    id "com.commercehub.gradle.plugin.avro" version "0.8.0"
}
apply plugin: 'java'
dependencies {
    compile externalDependency.avro
}
```

**settings.gradle** in **test**

```
def modules = [
    "test2"
]
modules.each { module ->
    include "${module}"
}
```

I am trying to convert it into maven. But I couldn't find how to add test2 module in test2 pom.xml to compile avro files. Please help me to solve this. Thank you.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why migrating from Gradle to Maven ?

Comment: I should convert it.  Could you please help me out.

Comment: You should convert it... but why ?

Comment: I do not understand "But I couldn't find how to add test2 module in test2 pom.xml" What do you mean by adding a module to a pom?

Comment: In gradle, test2 module is included  in externalDependency from settings.gradle. Then only my all avro are compiling to Java. I need to convert all those avro files using maven. Do you have any idea. pls

Comment: i don't know what the problem is exactly, however I'm keen to help. Do you have a SSCCE?

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand the problem at all, but I lack Gradle knowledge. Could you edit the question and add much more information about what you want to achieve and what goes wrong?